# Unity c# intptr to byte array without size info

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, intptr

My question is when you know rows and cols info of uchar* from c++, how i can convert it byte array. I have to give correct parameter to `Marshal.Copy`.

How can i convert intptr to byte array when i do not have size info? I've rows and cols info returned by c++, but i couldn't make it. Here is the code. When i implement that, unity crashes(boundary exception i guess).

```
                int rows = 0;
                int cols = 0;
                Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, pnt, imageData.Length);
                IntPtr returnPtr = cppExternalMethod(pnt, ref rows, ref cols);
                int size = rows * cols * 3; //i'm not sure about that
                byte[] result = new byte[size];
                Marshal.Copy(returnPtr, result, 0, size);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(returnPtr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
```

c++ part:

```
uchar* cppExternalMethod(uchar* frameData, int* rows, int* cols)
{
     Mat img(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC3);

    img.data = (uchar*)(frameData);
    Mat result = doWork(img);

    uchar* resultArray = result.data;

    Size s = result.size();
    int rows_ = s.height;
    int cols_ = s.width;
    *rows = rows_;
    *cols = cols_;
    return resultArray;
}
```

Edit: actually size = rows*cols*3 should work, i try for another project(where i now the size) and this equality holds.

Comment: You have rows and column....Is this a multidimensional array? Can you show the variable you are trying to return from C++? I just need to see how it is declared

Comment: "i'm not sure about that" => if one element is a byte, then it is right, otherwise it is too small.I'd say, `imageData.Length` would have to match `size` - check in the debugger whether it doesn't. where does the exception occur? what is `pnt` and where does `imageData` come from (type)?

Comment: Post the C++ signature.

Comment: @JohnWu no it is not, i could get rows and cols info but there is a problem when i convert it to byte.

Comment: The title and body o your question makes it a duplicate. You can't do that. You need to return the size of the data. I you are getting error or something, change the title and body to just reflect that. The question will be re-opened

Answer (score 1):

If your image is 3 channel (like RGB), your size is incorrect. Besides, you should use 'out' parameter instead of 'ref' with cppExternalMethod.

Comment: `ref` should work fine.

Comment: Yes it works fine, but it doesn't emphasize the intention.

Comment: Last OP's question talked about passing variable as reference. `ref` emphasizes  that.

Comment: it is the same for size = rows*cols*3, i'll try 'out' rather than ref.

Comment: The question says that the rows and cols are returned from C++ code. So they are output parameters. ref parameters are 2 way (both input and output) parameters. Since there is no need to read their initial values, it is a good practice to use {out} instead of 'ref'

Comment: Using 'out' will not solve your problem. It was just a recommendation. But fixing size, maybe..

Comment: I think your cpp code has a dangling pointer to data. Even if you get the rigth size, your data will be garbage.

Comment: ref works fine rather than out. and i guess #rows and #cols are correct. what i stucked is deciding correct size so that i can use it for that line `Marshal.Copy(returnPtr, result, 0, size)`

Comment: You have dangling pointer in your cpp code. When the result variable is out of scope, your data, which you are trying to copy using 'Marshal.Copy' will be invalid.

Comment: ok, i see your point, i'll try something else and let you know @tmguvenc

Comment: @tmguvenc i've corrected cpp part like that `int length = rows_ * cols_ * 3; uchar* tmpArr = result.data;
  uchar* resultArray = new uchar[length];

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
   resultArray[i] = tmpArr[i]; 
  }` still getting error on `int size = rows * cols * 3; //i'm not sure about that
                byte[] result = new byte[size];
                Marshal.Copy(returnPtr, result, 0, size);` lines.

Comment: Try passing the output array as ref and fill it in the cpp side.